# get last data from looping in c#

Tags: c#

I have the code for looping. 
and I need the latest data from the results of the looping. 
and from the last iteration, I just want to take the value "KodePosition" only. so how to get it? 
The following code example looping. 
please help me for this solution. 
thank you

```
foreach (string data in splitRow)
{
 string[] splitData = data.Split(';');
 DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
 dr["KodePosition"] = splitData[0];
 dr["NamaPosition"] = splitData[1];
 dr["UserLogin"] = splitData[2];
 dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Comment: What is SplitRow of Type , is that array - list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ASSUMING HERE THAT THE SPLITROW IS OF LIST TYPE.**

If you want last row and then the position column then you can use this approach.

```
        var lastRow = splitRow.Last();
        var lastPosition = lastRow.Split(';').First();
```

Make sure you have using System.Linq.

Answer (score 3):

If you are just trying to retrieve the value from the last row:

```
string lastKodePositionValue = dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count-1]["KodePosition"];
```

If this is not what you are looking to do, please be more specific.

Comment: sorry, not work. when debug.show error : "There is no row at position -1" thanks...

Comment: @AchmadDarmawan `x - 1 = -1`... when it's looking for the row at `-1` and you're subtracting `1` from the length of the array, that means your array has nothing in it... meaning you can't get the last row because it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the outside the scope of the foreach a variable to store the "KodePosition" and set that for each update in the loop.  Something like this

```
var lastKodePosition;
foreach (string data in splitRow)
{
 string[] splitData = data.Split(';');
 DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
 dr["KodePosition"] = splitData[0]; 
 lastKodePosition = dr["KodePosition"];
 dr["NamaPosition"] = splitData[1];
 dr["UserLogin"] = splitData[2];
 dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```